# Mysql looping over a list of files in directory

Tags: mysql

I want to insert files in my folder into mysql using the query below.

Structure of directory

```
1/
  --first.csv
  --second_123.csv
  --second_124.csv
  --second_125.csv

2/
  --first.csv
  --second_223.csv
  --second_224.csv
  --second_225.csv

LOAD DATA INFILE '/1/first.csv'
INTO TABLE tabel_name
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

How can I loop over the files to insert all the files. I want to write it in .sql file

Answer (score 3):

When you want to determine the file names with code, you can't. A database is not meant to be able to scan filesystems and so on. If it could, I'd have some serious security concerns. There is the `system` command in the mysql client, that let's you do things. But that's just for convenience. You can't parse the result of it.

Comment: Agreed. A better alternative is to wrap the database load code into a batch or shell script which can interact with the file system and use dynamic variables to run the data load.